# Load data by "id" for edit form using javascript in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to pass data from a table to edit a form, using JavaScript. The problem is that I am a complete newbie at JavaScript. Can someone at least help me by giving me an example of what the code should be?

I am not doing AJAX, just simple load data with JavaScript

**my model :**

```
function edit($a)
        {
        $d = $this->db->get_where('crud', array('idcrud' => $a))->row();
        return $d;
    }
```

**my controller :**

```
function edit()
    {
        $kd = $this->uri->segment(3);
        if ($kd == NULL) {
            redirect('Chome');
        }
        $dt = $this->Mcrud->edit($kd);
        $data['fn'] = $dt->firstname;
        $data['ln'] = $dt->lastname;
        $data['ag'] = $dt->age;
        $data['ad'] = $dt->address;
        $data['id'] = $kd;

        $this->load->view('Vhome', $data);
    }
```

And this is the button in the view, "Vhome", that I use as edit button :

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="edit(<?php echo $row->idcrud; ?>)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

That button will call JavaScript edit function that should call the data by "idcrud" :

```
function edit(idcrud)
    {
      $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
      $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
      $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title

      // I dont know what must i do here to call my data in table crud by "idcrud"


    }
```

And this is the form where the data gets passed to :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Surat Keluar</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body form">
        <form action="Chome/edit" method="post" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fn" class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fn" name="fn" placeholder="First Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ln" class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ln" name="ln" placeholder="Last Name">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ag" class="control-label col-md-3">Age</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ag" name="ag" placeholder="age">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ad" class="control-label col-md-3">Address</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ad" name="ad" placeholder="Address">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" name="mit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </form>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Can someone give me an example of what must I write in the JavaScript function edit?

edit :

This is full code of my view [Vhome.php](http://paste.ofcode.org/jmaMrz8sP74z7ESi9JEDwS)

Comment: The thing is, the data in your form must come from somewhere on the page, if you dynamically load it in the form fields with javascript. Can we see the view?

Comment: yes, you can. i has upload the view in the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's quite easy. First put some identifiers on this section:

```
foreach(...){  
...  
<tr id="idcrud<?php echo $row->idcrud;?>">
     <td class="idcrud"><?php echo $row->idcrud; ?></td>
     <td class="fn"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
     <td class="ln"><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
     <td class="age"><?php echo $row->age; ?></td>
     <td class="addr"><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

And in your `edit()` function:

```
 function edit(idcrud)
    {
        $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
        // MY EDIT:
        $("input #fn").val($("td #idcrud"+idcrud + " .fn").html());
        $("input #ln").val($("td #idcrud"+idcrud + " .ln").html());
        //and so on
    }
```

Some observation: Inside your form `<input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/>` will also need an `id` attribute : `<input id="id" type="hidden" value="" name="id"/>`. Then you can update it's value with: `$("input #id").val(idcrud);` in the `edit()` function.